# variant of tower of hanoi

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am having a really hard time coming up with the answer for the variants of tower of hanoi.
So the puzzle goes like this:
there are $n$ disks and $n+1$ pegs. There is also an adjacency restriction where at peg $i$, you can only move to peg $i-1$ or $i+1$.
I need an algorithm that runs at most $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ and $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$,
can anyone help me with this?
I solved the classic tower of hanoi with adjacency restriction and solved that the recursion solves to $3^n-1$ total moves. I am not sure how I should develop from this.

Comment: What is the goal of your algorithm? Moving the tower from peg 1 to peg 2? From peg 1 to peg n+1? Something else?

Comment: If there are $n$ disks and $n+1$ pegs, can you move each disk onto its own peg and then restack them?

Comment: I am only aware of a variant which can be solved in $2^n-1$ moves. Please clarify the new variants with , say , the cases $n=3$ and $n=4$ so that it becomes clear what the difference is.

Comment: As Henry said, you can just spread the discs out, at most one to each peg (this is O(n^2) ). Swapping two adjacent discs is 4 moves, so you can move the largest disc anywhere you want in O(n).  Finally build the tower again using such swaps, like the reverse of the first step (again O(n^2) ).

Comment: You should do this by hand for $2$, $3$ and $4$ rings. You will quickly see that you can move the entire stack to any adjacent peg in $O(n^2)$. Repeating that algorithm allows you to move the stack to any other peg in $O(n^3)$.

Comment: thanks for the help! I was able to get the algorithm to O(n^2) by swapping the disks, but I am not sure how it can go up to O(n^3). The problem asks me to find an algorithm that allows up to O(n^3)

Comment: An algorithm with complexity $O(n^2)$ is even better than what is required for $O(n^3)$. You need not search a worse algorithm , if you already found one better than what is required.

Answer (score 0):

1a. Move disk $1$ to peg $n+1$, $n$ moves
1b. Move disk $2$ to peg $n$, $n-1$ moves,  etc
Total $n(n+1)/2$ moves
2a. Move disk $1$ to peg $1$, $n$ moves
2b. Move the others up one, $n-1$ moves
3. Move disk $2$ to peg $2$, and the others up one
4. Etc until disk $k$ is on on peg $k$ for all $k$,
Total of steps $2$ to $4$ is $n^2$
5. Move all disks onto peg $n+1$, in $n(n+1)/2$ moves
Grand total $2n^2+n$ moves.
But the end of step 4 and the start of step 5 cancel each other, so it should be $2n^2+n-2$ moves